# iPhone SDK play mp4, avi, flv, 3gp, wmv formats on iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, video, uiwebview, avplayer

I have been in developing an iPhone app. In this app, I need to play various video files. I am using UIWebView with AVPlayer to play video file. mp4 videos are playing properly. But other formats (avi, flv, 3gp, wmv) are not playing.

My code works for mp4 but not for avi, flv, 3gp, wmv.

```
weakSelf.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = weakSelf.player;

[weakSelf addChildViewController:controller];
[weakSelf.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(weakSelf.webViewParentView.frame.origin.x, weakSelf.webViewParentView.frame.origin.y, weakSelf.browserWebView.frame.size.width, weakSelf.browserWebView.frame.size.height);
//NSLog(@"eeerror %@ ",[weakSelf.player error]);
//controller.view.frame = weakSelf.browserWebView.frame;
[weakSelf.player play];
```

How do I configure the app to play formats other then mp4? 
 Any suggestions are appreciated.